# Integral of $e^{x^2}$? Can we prove we need to invent a new name for this?

Tags: calculus, integration

My calculus classes were looking at
$$
\int e^{x^2} \, dx 
$$
today. I let them struggle with finding a solution. when I shared that the solution was impossible using the functions we know, and that we needed to define the “error function” to do this job, they asked me:

> How do we know there is no “known” solution to this integral? Have we proven we cannot find one with our regular algebraic functions?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered several times on this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral). You can also read more about this on [wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nonelementary_integral).